# Is $ k\mathbb{Z}_{N}\leq\mathbb{Z}_{N}$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

Consider the group $ \left(\mathbb{Z}_{N},+\right) $, which can be written explicitly by:

$$ \mathbb{Z}_{N}=\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}=\left\{ z+N\mathbb{Z}:z\in\mathbb{Z}\right\} ,$$

where $ N\mathbb{Z}=\left\{ N\cdot m:m\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}  $

Now consider $ n\mathbb{Z}_{N} $. I'm not sure if I understand correctly the meaning of $ n\mathbb{Z}_{N} $ (it appeared in my book), but I think it would be:

$$ n\mathbb{Z}_{N}=\left\{ nz+nN\mathbb{Z}:z\in\mathbb{Z}\right\} ,$$

which is not necessarily even a subset of $ \mathbb{Z}_{N}$.

But if we think of $ \mathbb{Z}_{N} $ as $ \mathbb{Z}_{N}=\left\{ \overline{0},\overline{1},...,\overline{N-1}\right\}  $, take for example $N=12$, then $ \mathbb{Z}_{12}=\left\{ \overline{0},\overline{1},...,\overline{11}\right\}  $ and we have, say for $n=8$, $ 8\mathbb{Z}_{12}=\left\{ \overline{0},\overline{8},...,\overline{88}\right\} =\left\{ \overline{0},\overline{4},\overline{8}\right\}  $ which is actually a subgroup.

Why does the actual definition of $ n\mathbb{Z}_{N}=\left\{ nz+nN\mathbb{Z}:z\in\mathbb{Z}\right\} $ not seem to be a subgroup when I write it explicitly, but when I use modulo notation it seems fine?

I'll show explicitly the difference:

$$ 8\mathbb{Z}_{12}=\left\{ 8z+96\mathbb{Z};z\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}  $$

and for example the set we get for $z=2 $ is $ \left\{ ...-176,-80,16,112,208...\right\}  $,

which is not one of the sets in $ \mathbb{Z}_{N}$.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $n\mathbb{Z}_N = \{ nz+N\mathbb{Z}\mid z\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. In general, if $A$ is an additive abelian group, $nA = \{na\mid a\in A\}$. So $n\mathbb{Z}_N = \{n(z+N\mathbb{Z})\mid z\in\mathbb{Z}\} = \{nz+N\mathbb{Z}\mid z\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: Your question seems to be: why is $nN\mathbb{Z} \subset N\mathbb{Z}$. Well, choose some number $nNk\in nN\mathbb{Z}$; then $nNk = N(nk)\in N\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $n\in \Bbb Z$.

---

We have

$$n\Bbb Z_N=\{n(a+N\Bbb Z)\mid a\in\Bbb Z\},$$

where

$$\begin{align}
n(a+N\Bbb Z)&=\underbrace{(a+N\Bbb Z)+\dots + (a+N\Bbb Z)}_{n\text{ summands}}\\
&=\underbrace{(a+\dots +a)}_{n\text{ summands}}+N\Bbb Z\\
&=na+N\Bbb Z
\end{align}$$

if $n\ge 0$, and

$$\begin{align}
n(a+N\Bbb Z)&=\underbrace{(-a+N\Bbb Z)+\dots + (-a+N\Bbb Z)}_{|n|\text{ summands}}\\
&=\underbrace{((-a)+\dots +(-a))}_{|n|\text{ summands}}+N\Bbb Z\\
&=na+N\Bbb Z
\end{align}$$

if $n<0$.

---

Let $H=n\Bbb Z_N$,  $G=\Bbb Z_N$.

We proceed using the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20one,is%20also%20in%20the%20subset.).

By definition, $H\subseteq G$.

Since $0+N\Bbb Z\in G$, we have $n(0+N\Bbb Z)=0+N\Bbb Z\in H$. Thus $H\neq \varnothing$.

Let $x,y\in H$. Then there exist $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ such that $x=na+N\Bbb Z, y=nb+N\Bbb Z$. Now

$$\begin{align}
x-y&=(na+N\Bbb Z)-(nb+N\Bbb Z)\\
&=(na-nb)+N\Bbb Z\\
&=n(a-b)+N\Bbb Z,
\end{align}$$

but $a-b\in\Bbb Z$, so $x-y\in H$.

Hence $H\le G$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that $ \underset{n\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\text{summands}}{\underbrace{N\mathbb{Z}+N\mathbb{Z}+...+N\mathbb{Z}}=nN\mathbb{Z}} $ which is not equivalent to $N\mathbb{Z}$. But I can see now that I was wrong.

Comment: You're welcome, @FreeZe.